# In Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, I can't see my sidebar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm missing the bigger buttons on my left sidebar. My sidebar looks like this:

[image]

But should look like this:

[image]

How do I get them back?

Thank you.

Comment: VS and VSC are different programs, so very likely they have a different GUI

Comment: Yup, wow I feel dumb. Thank you.